# Incorrect nested query output when use table name

Tags: mysql

I have encountered a very odd situation with MySQL (replicated with same results in PSQL) when a query return the right result when is used a table name alias but wrong result when is used full table name.

Please see below for full details:

We have the following 2 table COURSE and STUDENT
COURSE table has 2 records
STUDENT table have 12 records
(*I left out the FKs and any other attribute for example replication*)

[A live sample](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3wmdSL1uZP8pMU9ENRhBSb/1) or code below

```
-- Table structure for course
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `course`;
CREATE TABLE `course`  (
  `courseNo` int NOT NULL,
  `courseTitle` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`courseNo`)
);

-- Records of course
INSERT INTO `course` VALUES (1000, 'Software Engineering');
INSERT INTO `course` VALUES (1001, 'Internet Systems');

-- Table structure for student
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`;
CREATE TABLE `student`  (
  `studentid` int NOT NULL,
  `courseNo` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`studentid`)
);

-- Records of student
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3000, 1000);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3001, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3002, 1000);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3003, 1000);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3004, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3005, 1000);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3006, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3007, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3008, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3009, 1000);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3010, 1001);
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3011, 1001);
```

If I run the following nested query

```
SELECT c.courseNo AS 'Course ID',
       c.courseTitle AS 'Course Title',
       COUNT(s.studentID) AS 'Enrolled'
FROM course c,
     student s
WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
         FROM student
         WHERE s.courseNo = c.courseNo )
GROUP BY c.courseNo;
```

The result is correct 5 students are enrolled in course 1000, and 7 in course 1001.

| Course ID | Course Title | Enrolled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Software Engineering | 5 |
| 1001 | Internet Systems | 7 |

However if I run the following nested query

```
Select course.courseNo as 'Course ID',
       course.courseTitle as 'Course Title',
       COUNT(student.studentID) AS 'Enrolled'
From course,
     student
WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
         FROM student
         WHERE student.courseNo = course.courseNo )
Group by course.courseNo;
```

The result is

| Course ID | Course Title | Enrolled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Software Engineering | 12 |
| 1001 | Internet Systems | 12 |

They are exactly the same queries. The only difference is the alias in the table names.
If I do as a normal JOIN both versions are returning the correct result.

If anyone can explain this behavior of the nested query will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It seems  that `comma separated join` makes all the difference even though it is the same as join https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3wmdSL1uZP8pMU9ENRhBSb/2. What `MySQL` version are you using, is it `8+` ?

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use single quotes for identifiers such as column aliases. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL single quotes are usually for string (or date...) literals. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an error. Use backticks for identifiers that have special characters in them or are case sensitive or preferably don't use special characters and case sensitive identifiers at all. Identifiers don't need to be "pretty", "pretty" headers and such are a job for the presentation layer.

Comment: tried on 5.6, 8.0 and MariaDB 10.5 - all same output. I see your sample but the point was to eliminate the join. I know that it's work with a join in both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding starts from most local.

So in the second query `student.courseNo` binds to `student` from the *subquery* (as this is more local) whereas in the first query `s.courseNo` binds to `student` (aliased `s`) from the *outer query*.

So no, the queries are not "exactly the same".

To illustrate that you can use an alias in the subquery too. Then the second query would become

```
Select c.courseNo as 'Course ID',
       c.courseTitle as 'Course Title',
       COUNT(s.studentID) AS 'Enrolled'
From course c,
     student s
WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
         FROM student s2
         WHERE s2.courseNo = c.courseNo )
Group by c.courseNo;
```

and the first

```
Select c.courseNo as 'Course ID',
       c.courseTitle as 'Course Title',
       COUNT(s.studentID) AS 'Enrolled'
From course c,
     student s
WHERE EXISTS
        ( SELECT *
         FROM student s2
         WHERE s.courseNo = c.courseNo )
Group by c.courseNo;
```

(Notice that `courseNo` in the subquery references `s2` in the second and `s` in the first query.)

Comment: So this might explain the extra step in query execution when I run EXPLAIN. First one has 3 steps, second one has 4.

Answer (score 1):

your last query makes a cross join beteenn student and courses

```
From course,
 student
```

And then takes this cross join(try the result of that and count it yourself) and uses that to compare the data to a new student table not the one from the "FROM" clause and that are all rows

Use a proper JOIN to avoid confusion, with the same table name.

As the frist query you use the where compare the data from both tables in the3 "FROM" Clause and doesn't use the student table in the EXISTS select

> ```
> SELECT c.courseNo AS 'Course ID',
>        c.courseTitle AS 'Course Title',
>        COUNT(s.studentID) AS 'Enrolled'
> FROM course c INNER JOIN 
>      student s
> ON  s.courseNo = c.courseNo 
> GROUP BY c.courseNo;
> ```
>
> ```
> Course ID | Course Title         | Enrolled
> --------: | :------------------- | -------:
>      1000 | Software Engineering |        5
>      1001 | Internet Systems     |        7
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN SELECT c.courseNo AS 'Course ID',
>        c.courseTitle AS 'Course Title',
>        COUNT(s.studentID) AS 'Enrolled'
> FROM course c INNER JOIN 
>      student s
> ON  s.courseNo = c.courseNo 
> GROUP BY c.courseNo;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                     
> -: | :---------- | :---- | :--------- | :--- | :------------ | :--- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :-----------------------------------------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | null       | ALL  | PRIMARY       | null | null    | null |    2 |   100.00 | Using temporary                           
>  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | null       | ALL  | null          | null | null    | null |   12 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)
> ```

> ```
> EXPLAIN
> SELECT course.courseNo AS 'Course ID',
>        course.courseTitle AS 'Course Title',
>        COUNT(student.studentID) AS 'Enrolled'
> FROM course  INNER JOIN 
>      student 
> ON  student.courseNo = course.courseNo 
> GROUP BY course.courseNo;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                     
> -: | :---------- | :------ | :--------- | :--- | :------------ | :--- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :-----------------------------------------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | course  | null       | ALL  | PRIMARY       | null | null    | null |    2 |   100.00 | Using temporary                           
>  1 | SIMPLE      | student | null       | ALL  | null          | null | null    | null |   12 |    10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)
> ```

> ```
> Select course.courseNo as 'Course ID',
>        course.courseTitle as 'Course Title',
>        COUNT(student.studentID) AS 'Enrolled'
> From course,
>      student
> WHERE EXISTS
>         ( SELECT *
>          FROM student s
>          WHERE courseNo = course.courseNo )
> Group by course.courseNo;
> ```

> ```
> Course ID | Course Title         | Enrolled
> --------: | :------------------- | -------:
>      1001 | Internet Systems     |       12
>      1000 | Software Engineering |       12
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca714d3acf2bca80580274bd07dc1fa2)*